# PHPExcel type of a cell

Tags: excel, phpexcel

I am trying to use PHPExcel to export data to Excel.
It all works almost fine, but the cell where a telephone number is placed will strip the leading zero.

The code is as follows:

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(17, $row, "$data->telephone");`

Is there anyone with more experience to make the type of this cell the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have to define a DataType for it, and `TYPE_NUMBERS` will strip the leading zero, and since you don't define it, PHPExcel will match it against the value, and in this case use `TYPE_NUMBERS`. Therefore I would say something like this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('[COLUMN+ROW]')->setValueExplicit($data->telephone, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

or

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit("$row17", $data->telephone,PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

If I remember there was a bug a year or so ago, that caused this even when data type was specified, but it should be fixed by now!

Comment: No problems! Just mark the question as correct and good luck!